# JSONArray cannot get array based on indexPath

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am creating a Table list view from a JSon array. But I am not able to display the array name based on the indexPath. I tried indexOf but it is not available.

So let's say in row 1, it will display 'Testing' and in row 2, it will display 'Yeeea'. I am new to swift, got stuck here.. usually this should be simple :(

tt_array is defined

```
var tt_array: Array<Any>
```

Somewhere in the ViewDidLoad

```
self.tt_array = jsonObj["get_array_list"] as! Array
```

In our tt_array - **print(tt_array)**

```
[{
    "array_name" = Testing;
    ourid = 4;
    total = 2;
}, {
    "array_name" = Yeeea;
    ourid = 7;
    total = 1;
}]
```

In our cellForRowAt

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

var listthis = self.tt_array[indexPath] **error here**
        var array_name = listthis['array_name']


        cell.textLabel?.text = "TEST"

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
```

**Error says**: Cannot subscript a value of a type 'Array' with an index of type 'IndexPath'

Comment: What you get in tableview.?

Comment: I updated above: Error says: Cannot subscript a value of a type 'Array<Any>' with an index of type 'IndexPath'

Comment: Hi  In general We ll use indexPath.row only. Can you please self.tt_array[indexPath.row]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all declare the array with a more specific type

```
var tt_array = Array<[String:Any]>()
```

You have to get the **row** of the index path

```
let listthis = self.tt_array[indexPath.row]
```

and you have to downcast the value to `String`, btw: Swift does not support single quotes for literal strings.

```
let array_name = listthis["array_name"] as? String
```

Side note: This is not PHP or javascript, use *camelCased* variable names rather than *snake_cased*.

Answer (score 0):

This is your Answer.

```
var list = self.tt_array[indexpath.row] as? NSDictonary
var array_name = list["array_name"] as? String

print(array_name)
```